# Seeing logs from PID != 1

Tags: python, docker, logging, gunicorn

My docker container is running a django app, with gunicorn.

```
root@72981b4f355e:/usr/src/app# ps -ef
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMDq
root         1     0  0 15:32 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/gunicorn MyApp.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 3
root         9     1  1 15:32 ?        00:00:02 /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/gunicorn MyApp.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 3
root        11     1  1 15:32 ?        00:00:02 /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/gunicorn MyApp.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 3
root        12     1  1 15:32 ?        00:00:02 /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/gunicorn MyApp.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 3
root        21     0  0 15:35 ?        00:00:00 bash
root        28    21  0 15:35 ?        00:00:00 ps -ef
```

The logs show nothing, since the workers (the ones producing the logs), are not PID1.

How can I see the logs from the workers? Gunicorn is started as follows:

```
exec gunicorn MyApp.wsgi:application \
    --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 \
    --workers 3
```

Answer (score 1):

For access logs you can add `--access-logfile -` or maybe `--capture-output` if you want to see the workers stdout. You also may need to set PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 env var.

Source: http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html